# Why doesn't this code work? *Complete Noob*

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I recently started learning Python, and I wanted to create a program that will show me all the new releases from AllMusic, but it doesn't work. I'm sorry, but I'm a complete noob. At first I want to just see the artist:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def new_releases():
    url = "http://allmusic.com/newreleases"
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'artist'}):
        for a in div.findAll('a'):
            artist = a.string
            print(artist)

new_releases()
```

What am I doing wrong?
I don't get any errors, it jsut doesn't work for whatever reason

Comment: Well, here is the original link: http://www.allmusic.com/newreleases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your code is fine. But the site you are trying to grab prevents you from doing that. You'd find that out if you printed your soup this way: `print(soup)`.

To avoid that you may specify a User Agent (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)) header in your `requests.get`:

```
source_code = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

where `headers` is a dictionary like this:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'
}
```

Now it'll be working.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question.  You will need to make three changes to your code to make this work.  I have pasted the code that works below.  I have added

1. a definition of headers to support bs4 in finding the HTML it needs
2. added "features=lxml" so bs4 is looking for the right markup
3. added the headers attribute to the source_code definitions

   ```
   import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    def new_releases():
        headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'
        }
        url = "http://allmusic.com/newreleases"
        source_code = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features="lxml")
        for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'artist'}):
            for a in div.findAll('a'):
                artist = a.string
                print(artist)

    new_releases()
   ```

Comment: This are 7 years late gg

Comment: Its Not from me :), but U should answer fresh questions an Not old one that already answered Like u did serval Times ;)

Comment: Good call thanks.